# Need Google Drive v3 go SDK examples.

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I need example code for Google Drive API go sdk v3.  It's the only language missing from the examples doc at:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia

It's taking way too much trial and error for to get download of content working.

Comment: Also where do I get paid support for Google Drive Apps API?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) asking for sample code is offtopic for this forum. To make it on-topic, include your code and what is failing. There isnt paid API support from Google, unless possibly through their cloud platform paid support (at least $500 monthly)

Comment: My 2c is don't use the SDK. The REST API is well documented and easy to use.

Comment: I got paid Silver support from Google Cloud and they explicitly told me to post my question on stackoverflow with google-drive-sdk tag.  They don't support the Google Drive API even though my app is running on Google App Engine.  So I canceled Silver support and am now working with paid accounts for Google Apps for Work. I have a case open with them now to get the missing go sdk examples.

Comment: FYI, Silver Support is $150 a month presently. I'm guessing $500 a month is their platinum support.